# Python: finding which variable has the highest value and assign that value to a new variable

Tags: python

I want to be able to find the highest value of three different variables with their own integer value assigned to them. These are my variables:

```
firstscore = 1
secondscore = 7
thirdscore = 8
```

I want to find which of these variables has the highest value. To do this I created this code:

```
if firstscore > secondscore:
    if firstscore > thirdscore:
        highestscore = firstscore
    if thirdscore > firstscore:
        highestscore = thirdscore

if secondscore > firstscore:
    if secondscore > thirdscore:
        highestscore = secondscore
    if thirdscore > secondscore:
        highestscore = thirdscore

if thirdscore > firstscore:
    if thirdscore > secondscore:
        highestscore = thirdscore
    if secondscore > thirdscore:
        highestscore = secondscore
```

This code works fine if I had thee differently numbered variables (like above), and so the variable 'highest score' would be equal to 8 (highest number was thirdscore). However, if I use three variables and two of them share the same value (for example: instead of 1, 7, 8 I had 8, 8, 3), the variable 'highest score' is ***always*** 0! Can anybody explain why this is happening and if there is a way to address this issue in my code? I'm sure it's a logical problem, but I haven't figured out. I just can't get my head around it!

Comment: As for the *non-assignment*: When you have `(8, 8, 3)`, all the outer ifs have `False` conditions. Your assumption that this happens when two of the numbers are equals is close but not the whole deal, `thirdscore` also needs to be less than `firstscore`. All in all it's a lot simpler to just write `highscore = firstscore; if secondscore > highscore: highscore = secondscore; if thirdscore > highscore: highscore = thirdscore`. Or use the `max()` function.

Comment: Great point. Thank you so much! SO MANY ANSWERS! Thank you everyone for all your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that somewhere you initialize `highestscore` to `0`. Your conditional statements only handle cases where every number is strictly greater than another, rather than greater than or equal. This means that if two of those variables are equal to each other, `highestscore` doesn't get reassigned.

That said, the easiest way to find the highest score is as follows:

```
highestscore = max(firstscore, secondscore, thirdscore)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem straight away - I can't believe I hadn't thought of something this simple.

Answer (score 5):

the easiest way to do this, is:

```
highestscore = max(firstcore, secondscore, thirdscore)
```

However, I would recommend to have all values in a list, e.g.

```
a = [5, 2, 9, 23, 89, 42, 23, 49, 0, -3, -7]
```

and then do

```
highestscore = max(a)
```

The answer to your question, why your highestscore is always 0, is because you check only for greater than (and 8 is equal, or greater equal 8). That's why you don't go into any of you if paths.
Max is better, because of the simplicity and and can handle infinite number of arguments, instead of only three (four, five, six, ...). Also it's less error prone, because you have much less code ;)

Comment: This answer is not helpful, as it does not explains why OPs approach does not work, and why using max is better.

Comment: @Abhijit How is it not helpful? Why `max` is better. It's clear because of its simplicity.

Comment: @csharpcoder two things: max won't print, but will return a value. Second, You should not be interested in the variable _name_. But if you shoud be, you would put them in a dictionary and find the max value of the keys and then get the value. But one should simply not want that.

Comment: Here i hope, he is interested in Variable name too, Something like Who got highest , such comparison is used, See the Below post approach using dict. Anyways Your effort is appreciable, + 1 for compact and direct approach you have suggested.

Comment: @cookiesoft: Thank you so much for explaining why I kept getting 0. I appreciate everyone's input on this - and so fast! I swear I keep falling in love with this site every day.

Answer (score 1):

First, the most pythonic way to write the same thing would be:

```
highestscore = max((firstscore, secondscore, thirdscore))
```

Second, the code in the question is just wrong. You need to use **else** statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. This solved my problem - though I could only accept one answer. Thank you so much!