# determining the highest worth variable and printing the variable's name using python random

Tags: python

I've got this problem while i was making a project where i got 3 random generated numbers and want to determine the highest number and then using it's variable name and print out something like this:

```
print("the winner is:", winner, "with", winners_score, "points")
```

the "winner" is the teams name and the "points is the amount of points it had. I tried multiple ways to solve this problem including making a list and determining the highest score, etc. But i couldn't print the winner's name, only the winner's score. I then tried a dictionary with the name as key and the score as value and then the other way around. They both didn't work, i then tried .values() and .keys() but also didn't work. I finally created a piece of code to solve it but was too complex to use in a program with more than 10 variables. Here's the code of that test:

```
from random import *
score1 = randint(0, 51)
score2 = randint(0, 51)
score3 = randint(0, 51)

print(score1)
print(score2)
print(score3)
lister = [score1, score2, score3]
highest_score = max(lister)
winner = " "
if score1 > score2 and score1 > score3:
    winner = "score1"
elif score2 > score1 and score2 > score3:
    winner = "score2"
elif score3 > score1 and score3 > score2:
    winner = "score3"
else:
    winner = "nobody"
print("the highest score is", highest_score, "by", winner)
```

but this wouldn't work if i has a draw between the first two places. So how do i get the highest score and the winner with that score with a short(er) line of code
PS. I have also checked other questions on this website but both questions didn't give me the wanted answer, to read those:
[Finding The Biggest Key In A Python Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352887/finding-the-biggest-key-in-a-python-dictionary)
and
[Python: finding which variable has the highest value and assign that value to a new variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627142/python-finding-which-variable-has-the-highest-value-and-assign-that-value-to-a).
thank you for your help!

Comment: what would you like to happen if there is a draw?

Comment: i didn't have time to create that function @JoeIddon, i rather just wanted to create a short program to show what i could manage to create for my problem. And if there would be a draw i would have liked to make something like a penalty-shoot out between those 2 or even more if they all had a draw. with a random number between 0 and 10 or something

Comment: You do need to get this working correctly with a list or dict. Trying to do it with a bunch of numbered variables is messy, confusing & bug-prone.

Comment: should i add the code to my full project? Because the code i just posted was just a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of all according winner names to each score, then create list of all indices with the highest score and then create a list of all winners.

```
lister = [score1, score2, score3]
list_of_according_winner = ["score1", "score2", "score3"]

# list of highscore indices (if two are equal, you can have several elements)
highscore_index = [i for i, x in enumerate(lister) if x == max(lister)]

# create list of winners
winners = [list_of_according_winner[i] for i in highscore_index]

#printing
print("the highest score is", max(lister), "by", ", ".join(winners))
```

I omitted the option "nobody", as `max(lister)` will always have a value and therefore there will be always a winner, at least in the way as you implemented it.

Comment: It works good but what if the variable and team's names are different like what i have in my main program: team name is "blue" and the variable is "blue_voters"

Comment: This does not matter. It is just important that your `lister` has the same order than `list_of_according_winner`. If `lister = [blue,red,green]` then in this case the according winners list must be `list_of_according_winner = ["blue_voters", "red_voters", "green_voters"]`. Please note, that `list_of_according_winner ` is a list of strings and does have no relation to your variable names.

Comment: i am now creating a list from highest to lowest score and for some reason it gives a error that says: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. Has this something to do with the program you made or my own coding?

Comment: I think this will have to do with your code. If you are using `.remove()` command on an item that you already have removed you will get this error. I am not sure why you are using remove without seeing your code. I would recommend to do something like this `your_sorted_list = sorted(your_list,reverse=True)` then you will have it sorted from highest to lowest.

Comment: sorry, i just had found out that i phrased my question wrong! I was supposed to say "I am creating a top 10-like leaderboard (printed out)". I'm sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the name and score, this keeps those two bits of associated data together.  Use the built-in `sorted` function to get the highest score first, comparing the first two scores to check if there was a drawer.

```
from random import randint

l = []

def addTeam(name):
    l.append(
    {"name": name, "score": randint(0, 51)}
    )

def sortScores():
    return sorted(l, key=lambda t: t["score"], reverse=True)

def isDraw():
    if l[0]["score"] == l[1]["score"]:
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    addTeam("Team1")
    addTeam("Team2")
    addTeam("Team3")
    l = sortScores()

    if isDraw():
        winner = "nobody"
    else:
        winner = l[0]["name"]

    print("The highest score is {} by: {}".format(l[0]["score"], winner))
```

Try to avoid doing `*` imports, as this can lead to conflicts.